# finding string that contain special caracters in mongodb using $regex

Tags: mongodb

i want to search names that contains some special caraters like &, ô, à...

in my code i have this :

```
options.title = {'$regex': query, $options:'i'};
```

query may be name like that : `B&B Hôtel`

i have tried that code but it does not giving any thing, so any have an idea please.thank you for advance.

Comment: take a look at [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/)

Comment: @felix  
i want to search `B&B Hôtel`  names that contains  special caraters like & and ô by typing  `BB Hotel`